# Ubuntu Live CD isn't booting

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, livecd

I'm trying to boot an Ubuntu Live CD on Intel laptop. I wrote the 12.04 LTS (64 bits) bootable image from the official site to DVD, but it's not booting.

What steps am I performing wrong?

Comment: How many files are on the DVD you've written?

Comment: Is your system 64bit? Often the ISO is corrupted when downloading. Try to download, write to DVD and test again.

Comment: @gronostaj there are lots of files inside it.. Iso is 733MB

Comment: @KardNails downloaded file name is ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64

Comment: Erase the current ISO from your downloads folder and download it again. Then write the image and try to boot with the new DVD.

Comment: How old is the machine? Do you know if it has UEFI? Have you booted any other CDs/DVDs? Windows DVD, maybe?

Comment: @gronostaj Core i7 machine.It's UEFI enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter UEFI setup.

- Disable CSM
- Enable Legacy boot (or something that sounds similar)
- Make sure that your optical drive's boot priority is higher than hard drive's.

Note that disabling CSM will prevent already installed systems from booting.

Comment: Under the BOOT of my BIOS in the system,theres a heading called Boot Configurations.. In the default LAUNCH PXE OpROM -- Enabled... What should i do here ?(ther's a description here >> Controls the execution of UEFI and Legacy PXE oPROM )

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can disable it to make booting a bit faster, but it won't make any difference if you leave it enabled. It's just another feature most people don't need. It's not the "legacy boot" option you should look for in this case.